# Conditional probability of a poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

How could I calculate this conditional probability

${\large\mathsf P}\Big(N(5)-N(3)=6 \mid N(4) - N(3)=2\Big) $, N is a poisson process. Here is my try.

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)(*)}{P(B)}$.

but in the above case, (*) becomes ${\large\mathsf P}(N(4)-N(3)=2)$, then dividing it by itself, I get $P(1)$, but the answer is $P(N(1)=4)$. How?

Regards,

Comment: Let's be more concrete. Measure time in hours. There have been $2$ events from time $3$ to time $4$. What is the probability of $6$ events from time $3$ to time $5$? We need $4$ events from time $4$ to time $5$, so $4$ events in an hour. That yields the desired answer. One can also do a more formal conditional probability calculation.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. @AndréNicolas

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

${\large\mathsf P}\Big(N(5)-N(3)=6 \mid N(4) - N(3)=2\Big) = {\large\mathsf P}\Big(N(5)-N(4)=4\Big)$

By reason that since you know that two of the six events occurred in the first half of the period, and Poison Processes are *memoriless*, so you only need to find the probability that the four remaining events occur in the second half of the period.

Alternatively:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
 \mathsf P\Big(N(5)-N(3)=6 \mid N(4) - N(3)=2\Big) 
& = \frac{
  \mathsf P\Big(N(5)-N(3)=6\cap N(4)-N(3)=2\Big)
}{
 \mathsf P\Big(N(4)-N(3)=2\Big)
}
\\[2ex] & = \frac{
  \mathsf P\Big(N(5)-N(4)=4\cap N(4)-N(3)=2\Big)
}{
 \mathsf P\Big(N(4)-N(3)=2\Big)
}
\\[2ex] & = \frac{
  \mathsf P\Big(N(5)-N(4)=4\Big)\;\cancel{\mathsf P\Big( N(4)-N(3)=2\Big)}
}{
 \cancel{\mathsf P\Big(N(4)-N(3)=2\Big)}
}
\\[2ex]
 \mathsf P\Big(N(5)-N(3)=6 \mid N(4) - N(3)=2\Big) 
 & = 
  \mathsf P\Big(N(5)-N(4)=4\Big)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, as in the hint from Andre, the *intersection* tells you there are 2 events in $(3,4)$ *and* that there are 4 events in $(4,5).$ But these are non-overlapping intervals and
therefore associated events are independent. (You are not thinking
clearly about the intersection.)

Is the probability
of 4 events in $(4,5)$ the same as the probability of 4 events in $(0,1)?$
If so, what two properties of the Poisson process come into play in
establishing that? And what is another way to write that?